# Future kernel features for 5.15.0 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, kernel, 22.04

The current kernel version (5.15.0) has disabled my PC wifi adapter (Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565) as well as the Bluetooth. I can boot up on a USB live version of Mint-Mate and the adapter is detected and works as advertised.

There is a older 5.4.0 kernel installed but if I attempt to boot on it I get an immediate kernel panic. I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 (Beta), so there's no going back from there.

My question is, since my wifi is broken in 22.04 is there any way to know if my adapter module will be restored in the future? Because, if it is not I will be replacing Ubuntu 22.04 with another option. I'd prefer to not do that but I may not have a choice.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is currently in pre-release testing. It is not released software. Keep in mind that the sort of problem you describe is called a *reversion*, and it's a bug. The Beta testing period is intended to discover and report exactly these kinds of problems. When it will be fixed is discussed on the bug report -- assuming somebody else has reported the bug. If not, report it! Next time, test your hardware using a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment --that's why it's there-- before committing to an install.

Comment: Understood, thanks. For the record, the reversion had occurred before I did the upgrade, so it affects 20.04 as well. I mistakenly thought that the upgrade may fix it.

Comment: There's no data in your tale that would help find a solution. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting and https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After following the recommended steps from @waltinator and others I discovered that the driver/module ath9k was not being loaded.

I could enter modprobe ath9k and the adapter would immediately become available. The fix was not persistent though, even after adding an entry to /etc/modules.

I then discovered that the module was blocked from loading in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. A comment-out of that entry and the adapter is back to normal.